# Is it possible to restore flutter shared preferences data with device backup?

Tags: database, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make flutter application with specific data storage requirements:

1. Data is stored in a safest way possible
2. If data is changed or deleted, there is no way back

So i am looking for plugin/custom solution that can prevent any data changes on device backup's or other system cases.

Is it possible to make application data invisible for system backup?

Can i use shared preferences/ or i'd better pick another plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the reason for those data storage requirements? There may be a better solution that trying to prevent the data from being backed up.

Comment: for example you are making sending guarantee that you have spent some amount of money, so if u back up data on device you can spend them twice or more times (there could be deffered method to prevent that)

Comment: That's true, but in some places there is no internet, but people still can use their devices for some actions

Comment: You store some data locally, but you should not rely on it. Your actual issue is unclear and your question is asking about how to achieve your attempted solution, not your actual problem. See [What is the XY probem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should also look into existing solutions. Your problem is unclear so I cannot link you to anything specific.

Comment: You can use `flutter_secure_storage` for encrypting the data. Any change in there will break the data & decrypting won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using shared preferences as too much has system overhead, so i recommend to you for using another table on you local storage for deleting record from anywhere of you app.